# Calling a function inside of a lambda expression

Tags: c#, function, lambda

In C#, is it possible to call a function inside of a `lambda` expression?

For example, here are some contents of `lambda` expression:

```
(a => a.testBool && a.testBool2)
```

Is it possible to write the above contents into a function, and call the function inside of the `lambda` expression to get the same results?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

In my original post, I did not state that this is for a dbSet.

I have created the following function in the test object (a) as follows:

```
public bool testBool()
{
    return true;
}
```

When calling the following code:

```
(a => a.testBool()).ToList()
```

I am getting this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean testBool()'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: ofcourse you can call a method from a lamda, lambdas are also methods.there is nothing special about them. so you can do anything you do in a normal method.

Comment: Have you tried to write the above contents into a function, and call the function inside of the lambda?

Comment: Are you using the lambda to create a delegate, or to create an expression tree? If you're trying to create a delegate, it's easy. If you're trying to create an expression tree, it's still possible, but a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if its a function declared in class a.

```
public class a
{
    bool testBool()
    {
     ...
    }

    bool testBool2()
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
ListA.Where(a => a.testBool() && a.testBool2()).ToList();
```

Comment: Sure this will work? With a `void` function?

Comment: You're right, corrected the answer ;)

Comment: That method needs to return a boolean; and it should be "Linq to objects". Don't try it with "Linq to SQL"

Comment: are you confusing the projected instance of 'a' (in the lambda) with a class 'a'. in your example where are you instantiating a?

Comment: @DaveBecker I'm assuming `ListA` is an instance of `List<a>` that already contains items. That part of the answer looks okay to me.

Comment: Im assuming nothing. The answer is no different to the OPs example except that testBool is now a function not a property. Not quite what they asked.

Comment: Why -1? I've just given him an example how this could work. I just didn't want to answer with an simple "Yes!". :S

Comment: @kassi: Can you have a look at my edit please?